# Получение смс кода android на python

Tags: python, android

у меня есть программа полностью написанная на python, которая осуществляет вход по номеру телефона и смс-коду. Мне надо, чтоб программа подставляла код автоматически, для этого получать само смс, подскажите как можно реализовать получение смс и запись его в переменную. Спасибо.